# How do you extend the height of a collection view and not have scrolling, but have scrolling on the outside view?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Right now, I have a collection view with scrolling inside a view.

I'd like the collection view's height to expand downward depending on how much content it has and not have any scrolling.

A user would then scroll from the outside view.

The collection view is the last section in the screenshot:

[image: View Controller with collection view inside of the view]

I tried using a table view with one cell having a collection view and that did not work.

Comment: ***Why*** do you want to do that? `UICollectionView` is designed to efficiently manage memory, display, scrolling, etc. If you try to "expand" the collection view to show *every* cell, you're defeating the purpose. If you only have a few cells, there are more efficient ways to do what you're asking.

Comment: What you need is a stack view

Comment: @DonMag I'd like the whole view to scroll instead of just the collectionView so I'm probably not doing it the efficient way. I am fairly new to Swift so I do not know what I'm doing. I only chose collection view because I want to show the cells side by side taking up 50% of the width. In the future, I'd only like to show the first 20 results, so would not be showing every result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I am fairly new to Swift..."*

You may want to first spend some time researching ***different*** ways to layout UI elements.

Depending on how many "repeating" elements you'll potentially have, you might want to take this approach:

[image]

If you'll potentially have ***many, many*** "repeating" views (cells), you might be better off using a collection view - with its built-in memory management - using one of these approaches:

[image]

Or, possibly a collection view with a Compositional Layout.

In any case, trying to "expand the collection view to show all the cells and then scroll the whole thing" defeats the purpose of using a collection view, and is *rarely* the appropriate way to go.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'll spend some time researching different ways to layout UI elements first and then go through your approaches to see which one may be the best fit. Thank you for putting all of that together and for explaining why.